# alignment of a Progress View in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

XCode 12.5.1

I have a Bar Timer View and a Progress View in a Stack View.

```
Stack View:
Axis = Vertical
Alignment = Fill
Distribution = Fill
```

Also I added the following constraints to the Bar Progress View:

```
Progress View.centerX = centerX
Progress View.leading = leading + 10
trailing = Progress View.trailing + 10
height = 10
```

A have the following issues in the Interface Builder:

1. After changing my Progress View to Bar Progress View it became even narrower. In the same time everything is fine in the Emulator.
2. There are no gaps between the Progress View and edges of the screen. Again all is OK in the Emulator.

Are there any ways to fix it except upgrading to the 13.1?

3. As with other Views I was expecting that it would be located at the center of the 2nd half of the Stack View.  But why my Bar is at the bottom of the Stack View?

[image]